# Is there combinatorial recurrence with radicals?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, radicals

Is there recurrence relation for combinatorial objects which have root on right-hand side? I found that formula for problem in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2333947/find-formula-for-number-of-dominated-vectors-in-partial-order) is of such type and want to find similar formulas and methods to obtain them and corresponding area of combinatorics.
Example of triangle of numbers (from simple variant of mentioned question):

```
    [1]    
    [1, 4]    
    [1, 9, 16]    
    [1, 16, 49, 64]    
    [1, 25, 121, 225, 256]    
    [1, 36, 256, 676, 961, 1024]
```

In it $A[x][y] = A[x-1][y-1] + A[x-1][y] + 2*\sqrt{A[x-1][y-1] * A[x-1][y]}$

Comment: Can you give us more details of what you wish to find out?

Comment: You mean like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression, the Fibonacci numbers given by a formula involving $\sqrt{5}$?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "combinatorial objects", what you mean by "closed form formula", what you mean by "have root" and what you mean by "right-hand side."  Depending on your answers to those, the answer is probably "obviously yes," a simple example being something like "Let $T(n)$ be the number of layers needed to stack $n$ objects into a pyramid-like shape."  Whether any of the examples which have roots are "interesting" to you is another question entirely.

Comment: @Hans Lundmark: Sorry, I meant recursion, not closed form.

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124560/how-to-approach-2-dimensional-recurrence-relations

Answer (score 1):

The numbers $A[x,y]$ are the squares of the number of OEIS sequence [A008949](http://oeis.A008949) which has the same recursion as Pascal's triangle for binomial coefficients. So, if you let $A[x,y]:=T[x,y]^2$, then $T[x,y]=T[x-1,y-1]+T[x-1,y]$ and the "radical" disappers. We can rewrite the recursion as $A[x,y]=A[x-1,y-1]+A[x-1,y]+2T[x-1,y-1]T[x-1,y]$ using $T[,]$.

This does not answer your question, but it is unlikely that the recurrences you want exist.

Comment: This is a solution of combinatorial problem, not just squares of another sequence.